# Docker Nginx-Proxy Container used for Port 80 Forwarding to other container based on Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, proxy

I am trying to set up a Docker Nginx Proxy server to forward incoming requests to their corresponding Docker Container on 192.168.1.120 or to the Router's Web-Admin at 192.168.1.1

So right now I am in a bit of a pickle, but I need to set this up regardless. I have this setup right now

```
Router 192.168.1.1 (Web Admin + Port Forwarding)
Server1 LAMP   - (Router Forwards -> port 80 for LAMP Server)
Server2 Docker - (Router Forwards -> 20 SSH, 8080, 9000 Docker Admin)
```

So I have to configure the port forwarding through my Router's web interface, which is accessible on port 8080. But the issue is that right now I moved to Florida, and I had stupidly added a port-forwarding rule on 8080 to forward to Shipyard Docker Manager, which I eventually planned to install an Nginx-Proxy Forwarding Docker container. I never got the forwarding Docker container working, and I eventually switched to Portainer on port 9000 which I had to configure because it was the only other port I had already set forwarded before I lost access to my Router's web interface, and thus lost the ability to forward ports.

The downside is that I cannot access my Router's web interface. The upside is that - I still have to implement an Nginx-Proxy port forwarding Container anyways, to set up dynamic port 80 forwarding to different Docker containers based on the URL.

So I want to mvoe my LAMP server on as a new Docker Container, and then I will also have a few other Rails Docker containers - but I need to configure a Docker Container to forward the app to differnt servers based on the port. I assume I need to have 2 dockers running - one for port 80 forwarding, and then one for port 8080 forwarding - this is not a problem.

I have not been able to correctly configure my Nginx config to forwarding an incoming request from my domain-name that I have point to my server (my.domain.com below), needs to get forwarded to my router 192.168.1.1. Any help / suggestions on how to configure my Nginx-Proxy Docker Container to forward this correctly, or what I should setup here to forward incoming requests to a web-server dynamically based on the URL. I can install any Docker containers I need for this.

```
My current Config /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, running on a Nginx-Proxy Docker Container on port 8080 (Google to find the Docker Image for nginx-proxy)


# My Nginx Config to forward my.domain.com
http {
  resolver 127.0.0.1;
  access_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log;
  server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name my.domain.com;
      return 301 http://192.168.1.1:8080/$request_uri;
  }
}


I get these errors:

[error] 55#55: *2274 datacenter.URL.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out), client: 166.172.189.185, server: datacenter.URL.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "datacenter.URL.com:8080"
[error] 55#55: recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 192.168.1.1:8080
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that I can only have one Docker Container running at-a-time for each port. So I need to figure out how to forward requests to different servers's + ports based on the Domain Name. So each URL forwarding rule entry needs to be able to go to different servers all running on all different ports.